# Don't set a Gtk.TreeView's selection when focusing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, pygtk, gtk3

The following code displays a window with a button and tree view.  A handle for the 'clicked' signal is attached to the button and focuses the tree view.  When the window is initially displayed, the tree selection has no selected items, but when the tree view receives focus, the first item is automatically selected.  Is there a way to keep a selection from being made when the tree view receives focus?

[image: window before clicking]   [image: window after clicking]
*Before click, button has focus and tree selection has no selected items. After click, tree view has focus, but an item has been selected.*

The issue that arises from this is that I have an interface that keeps some things in sync by attaching to the 'changed' signal on the tree selection of the tree view.  When the window is displayed, depending on where the tree views are in the interface, they may receive focus by default.  That causes a 'changed' signal, and unexpected synchronization happens.  It's possible to call **set_can_focus(False)** for all the tree views, but that:

1. only prevents keyboard cycling focus, not programmatic focus, and the selection still turns on with programmatic focus; and
2. seems to disable the ability to *deselect* a selection (e.g., by control-clicking on a row).

Similarly I can use **grab_default** to ensure that something else gets focus first when the window is displayed, but it doesn't keep a stray focus event from making an unexpected selection.

Based on [a posted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28190626/1281433) that says that says that selection mode SINGLE "requires at least one item to be selected", and that that explains why an element is selected on focus, I looked more into the selection mode constants.  Of these, **SINGLE** and **BROWSE** seem most relevant.  The pygtk documentation, [GTK Selection Mode Constants](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/gtk-constants.html#gtk-selection-mode-constants), only says that:

> `gtk.SELECTION_SINGLE` A single selection allowed by clicking.
>   `gtk.SELECTION_BROWSE` A single selection allowed by browsing with the pointer.

The GTK+3 documentation, [enum GtkSelectionMode](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Standard-Enumerations.html#GtkSelectionMode), goes into a bit more detail:

> `GTK_SELECTION_SINGLE` Zero or one element may be selected.
>   `GTK_SELECTION_BROWSE` Exactly one element is selected. In some
>   circumstances, such as initially or during a search operation, it’s
>   possible for no element to be selected with GTK_SELECTION_BROWSE. What
>   is really enforced is that the user can’t deselect a currently
>   selected element except by selecting another element.

I don't see anything here to suggest that at least one element must be selected when the selection mode is SINGLE.

Here's code to reproduce the window and serve as an example.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

# A ListStore with some words
list_store = Gtk.ListStore(str)
for selection in "Can a machine think?".split():
    list_store.append([selection])

# A TreeView with a single column
tree_view = Gtk.TreeView(model=list_store)
cell_renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
tree_view_column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(cell_renderer=cell_renderer,text=0,title='Words')
tree_view.append_column(tree_view_column)

# A button to focus the list
focus = Gtk.Button(label='Focus List')
focus.connect('clicked',lambda *_: tree_view.grab_focus())

# A Box to hold everything, and a Window for the Box.
box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
box.add(focus)       # button on top gets initial focus
box.add(tree_view)   # tree_view below doesn't, and has no selected items 
window = Gtk.Window()
window.add(box)
window.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

Comment: I suppose one option would to connect and connect_after handlers for the 'focus' signal, and save and restore the existing selection with them.  That feels a bit kludgy, but maybe it would work in the meantime until a better solution is found.  It would be surprising if that's the best way to do it, though.

Comment: Make new widget that mixed with ‍`VBox`, `Button` and a `TreeView` and connect related events to actions for controling the focus.

Comment: Looking at the source: https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtktreeview.c?id=93c3b90f6a88dd2eb80661bec002fa9ebb729d65#n8692 gtk_tree_view_focus_to_cursor always gets called when tree_view.grab_focus() gets called. I don't know your use case, but maybe you want to log a bug to add a feature to allow you to prevent this. http://bugzilla.gnome.org/  (Your understanding of selection mode constants is correct. With SINGLE, you can ctrl-click to get back to zero selection.)

Comment: @Mohsen I'm not sure what you're trying to say.  What you're suggesting is essentially what I've already done *to demonstrate the problem.*  The problem is that I don't see why a selection should be set when the tree view is focused.

Comment: You can make new `TreeView` widget with new face by using cairo library that handle independent focus and selection, but this way is very difficult.

Comment: @Mohsen That might be a workaround, but it doesn't sound like the simplest work around, and it doesn't really answer the question of why GTK is behaving in the way it is (which its docs don't suggest).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source in [root/gtk/gtktreeview.c for tree_view.grab_focus()](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtktreeview.c?id=93c3b90f6a88dd2eb80661bec002fa9ebb729d65#n8692), we can see that gtk_tree_view_focus_to_cursor always gets called, and selects the first element.  You can work around this, in some cases, though.

This is a nasty hack.

It overrides the `grab_focus` method, stores the selection before calling `grab_focus`, and clears the selection afterwards if there was no selection before.

```
def tree_view_grab_focus():
    selection = tree_view.get_selection()
    _, selected = selection.get_selected()
    Gtk.TreeView.grab_focus(tree_view)
    if selected is None:
        selection.unselect_all()

tree_view.grab_focus = tree_view_grab_focus
```

Unfortunately it only applies when calling `grab_focus` from Python, other callers (such as GTK's keyboard navigation) don't.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable implementation of what [I'd mentioned in the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28173567/dont-set-a-gtk-treeviews-selection-when-focusing#comment44717171_28173567).  Rather than overriding the grab_focus method, I wonder if two functions could be connected with `connect` and `connect_after` that would work in all situations.  It would be nice to add the content from [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28173567/dont-set-a-gtk-treeviews-selection-when-focusing#comment45152091_28173567) to this answer, since it explains the behavior.